Not able to fetch text file's data which has stored inside S3 bucket
I have a text file which I have stored inside AWS S3 Bucket. Link: https://documentation-test-mk.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/sample-text+file.txt
When I'm trying to open this file from incognito, I can able to open it. But when I trying to do this from console, getting an error from the console:

My Configuration is as follows:
a. I have unchecked Block all public access
b. Bucket policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::documentation-test-mk/*"
        }
    ]
}

c. Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 30000
    }
]

Can anyone help me by which I can extract the text?

This is not a problem with s3 but with your frontend. you have a content security policy(CSP) configured on your frontend. That restricts it from loading the file. If you add the s3 url to your CSP or make it less restrictive it should work.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy
